# Flutter Firestore set document if document doesn't exists

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set a document if it doesn't exists and if it exists throw an error. I tried with `mergeFields: []` which makes the `set` not overwriting the document, but it still doesn't throw an error. It's there any way to do this?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("reservations").doc("test").set(
                          {
                          "name" : "John",
                          },SetOptions(mergeFields: [])).then((_){
                              print("success!");
                          })
                          .catchError((_) {
                            print("not successful!");
                          });
```

Comment: Remove `.toString())` and comment your output here.

Comment: Sorry, that `.toString())` it's not in my code, I just copied it wrong, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mergeFeilds` doesn't check whether the document is exist or not but fields inside the document see [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions#properties_1).

Try this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("reservations").doc("test").get().then((doc){
  if(!doc.exists){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("reservations").doc("test").set(
                      {
                      "name" : "John",
                      })
                      .catchError((_) {
                        print("not successful!");
                      });
  }else print('Document already exists');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`add`

Example:

```
const vals = {
    time: time,
    phone: phone,
    name: name,
    email: email
}
return admin.firestore().collection('claims').add(vals);
```

Comment: I want my document to have a specific id and when trying to add a document with the same id I want to throw an error to let me know that the document already exists, so `add` doesn't help me. Thanks for your answer anyway.